# How can I stop a KafkaSpout?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I have a topology that is reading from Kafka using a KafkaSpout and then POSTing in a rest api. The problem is that the API has some maintenance periods, so it is not available for a period of time, my question is How can I stop processing messages by using a kafka spout?, I found an api named storm-signals [enter link description here](https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-signals) the problem about it is that I can't change the implementation of the kafka spout to make it inherit of the BaseSignalSpout.
Is there any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just deactivate the topology. You can do this via the Storm CLI, Storm UI, the Storm REST API or a Nimbus client (Java or otherwise). The spout will stop emitting until you reactivate the topology.

Comment: The problem is that i don't want to stop all the process, I just want to stop one part, because it handles multiple markets and other markets must be up and running

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, you have many spouts in your topology, and you want to stop only the KafkaSpout. I think the easiest way to do this would be that you split your topology up so you get a topology that only has the KafkaSpout. Alternatively, maybe it would be possible to add the ability to deactivate only a subset of a topology's spouts. You can raise an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa, and if you like raise a PR at https://github.com/apache/storm/pulls.